# changing value of a component property via template

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a component like this:

import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'topic-details',
  templateUrl: './detailpane.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detailpane.component.scss']
})
export class DetailpaneComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() topics;
  myprop;
  constructor() { }
  assign(property,value){
      property = value;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And in my template:

```
<button (click)='assign(myprop,"some value")'>testing</button>
{{myprop}}
```

**Take a look at the myprop property. In essence assign method has no effect! I was expecting myprop in the template to refer exactly same myprop in the component. I am beginnning to think that as soon as myprop goes out of the component inside the template, it becomes local to the template and doesn't reference the component (original) property.**

Any explanation would be great!

Answer (score 0):

showPane is a primitive, thus is immutable.
This is more a javascript thing than an angular 2 issue.

you can either set it the template (my favorite)

```
(click)='showPane = !showPane'
```

or use an object

```
//in class
flagsCollection = {showPane:false}

toggle(flag){
  this.flagsCollection[flag] = !this.flagsCollection[flag];
}


// in template
(click)='toggle("showPane")'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the value to wrong property, your `property` below, only exists in that function:

```
assign(property,value){
  property = value;
}
```

but you want to assign it to `myProp` instead, which is also the variable you display in your view:

```
assign(property,value){
  this.myProp = value;
}
```

Make notice of the keyword [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

And if you actually have just one `myProp` (and not part e.g of iteration), you don't need to pass it to the function, just the new value:

```
<button (click)='assign("some value")'>testing</button>

assign(value){
  this.myProp = value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your toggle method change locally the flag parameter. If you want to update showPane you could try this :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'topic-details',
  templateUrl: './detailpane.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detailpane.component.scss']
})
export class DetailpaneComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() topics;
  showPane = false;
  constructor() { }
  toggle(){
      this.showPane = !this.showPane;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

<div class="col-md-12 list-group topics" [ngClass]="{'topics-small':showPane}" >
   <a  class="list-group-item cursor-pointer"

   *ngFor='let topic of topics' 
   (click)='toggle()'
   >{{topic.name}}</a>>

</div>
```

Comment: no i want to have a generic toggle function. so if i have another flag variable like showPane2, I just do toggle(showPane2).